# As a Scrum Master, what could I do to encourage devops in my company?

Tags: scrum, agile, scrum-master, devops

DevOps – a cultural and professional IT movement focused on changing the mindset of how organizations function – will no doubt make a significant impact across many companies. In my companies, we have a portfolio of products that needs no downtime delivery. We want to apply DevOps, so as the scrum master, how can I contribute to the process?

Comment: Do you have a Dev team? Do you have an Ops team? Are you going to create a DevOps team? What has kept you from doing it until now?

Comment: @nvoigt Should it be a separate team? Couldnt DevOps responsibilities be part of a Scrum-team?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal In theory, yes. In practice, there is not much left of your planned Scrum approach if you have to handle Ops too, which basically is the iconic Kanban domain.

Comment: @nvoigt We have Dev team, but no Ops team. Dev team handles all jobs of Ops team (if it exists): releasing, deploying, monitoring. In my company, dev team is learning tool (vagrant, docker swarm, docker compose, ansible, etc..) to make deployment more smoothly, to the "no downtime" deployment extent. They are technical, but I'm a scrum master (SM), a PM and not involve too deeply in technical things. I'm wondering what other things I can do to help the team as SM.

Comment: If your Dev team does all the Ops work, then you already have DevOps. Can you point out where you think the problem lies or what this new "DevOps" buzzword could bring to the table that your team does not do already?

Comment: DevOps is a set of practices that are applied, not a team. If your team is on the line for zero-downtime you need to  be actively removing impediments. Having a separate ops team would be on such impediment.

Comment: Are you sure that devops is the answer, and your management isn't just looking for a way to justify forcing the developers to wear more hats? Also, it's fine if you want devops, but be aware that this will, by definition, reduce the influence you have on the developers who used to follow just scrum, and their capacity to meet the project needs of the customers they have been working with.

Answer (score 1):

As a Scrum Master you influence the development approach by coaching and advising.

Some areas you might want to consider coaching in are:

- The benefits of cross-skilling and having a [t-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-shaped_skills) skills profile
- Treating [infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_Code) (such as including config in source control and testing it alongside the code)
- Encourage more training in the appropriate areas
- Evangalise about the benefits of having a joined up approach to development and operations

Comment: it is good to hear about the 2nd thing you mentioned "Treating infrastructure as code" because I also heard about it from our dev team - they realized the benefit of it and actually introduced some techniques among the team.